# Azure Cloud - creating Automation Account - Bad request error

Tags: azure, automation

I am sorry I am quite fresh in Azure as well as this is my the first question on Stackoverflow and I found a problem while creating an Automation Account either with use of Azure Portal or with use of Power Shell. I get the same error "Bad request" - description "Message":"Something went wrong. Please contact support."} (code: BadRequest)"
The command I use in PowerShell is
`New-AzAutomationAccount -Name 'Azure-AA' -Location 'EastUS' -ResourceGroupName 'Azure-AA-RG'`
I can't figure out what is wrong and why I can't create an Automation Account?

Comment: I just ran your command in both Cloud Shell and PowerShell, and it works fine. What version of PowerShell are you running? `$PSVersionTable`? Have you tried to use `Az CLI` instead? `az automation account create --automation-account-name "Azure-AA" --location "East US" --sku "Free" --resource-group "Azure-AA-RG"`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/automation/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-automation-account-create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Verify below:***

- Check the name of automation account you are giving because Azure has a very strict naming convention pattern. It should contain only `letters, numbers, and hyphens`. Cross verifies it and change accordingly for successful deployment.
- Check and update the PowerShell modules to the latest version to avoid conflicts.
  `Get-InstalledModule -Name Az* | Update-Module`
- **"Bad request"** error may also occur due to issues related to the specified **region**. Deploy the Automation Account in a different region than the one you are currently working in.
- Check the subscription limits by visiting `subscriptions >> Usage + quotas` to check the cost limit as it may block the creation of an automation account if the limit has exceeded.

*I tried creating an automation account with both* `CLI` *as well as* `PowerShell` *and the deployment was successful as shown below.*

***PowerShell:***

[`New-AzAutomationAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/new-azautomationaccount?view=azps-11.2.0)

```
New-AzAutomationAccount -Name "TodayAutomationAccount" -Location "East US" -ResourceGroupName "xxxx"
```

[image]

***Bash (CLI):***

[`az automation account create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/automation/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-automation-account-create)

```bash
az automation account create --automation-account-name "CLIAutomationAccount" --location "East US" --sku "Free" --resource-group xxxx
```

[image]

***Azure Portal:***

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It seems many people have the same issue. I created the same question on Microsoft Q&A website and the answers suggest it is a problem with Azure Portal itself
[link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1514806/azure-cloud-creating-automation-account-bad-reques

Comment: It might be the problem these days but the above given points are based on the common scenario. @Arek

Comment: Thank you @Naveen Sharma, I'll do so